# Print results side by side SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have following result set,

[image: Check this attached url for result set]

Now with above results i want to print the records via select query as below attached image

[image: Click here to view desired output of report]

Please note, I will have only two types of columns in output Present Employee & Absent Employees.

I tried using pivot tables, temporary table but cant achieve what I want.

Comment: No only 2 columns. Present and Absent.

Comment: Include CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements in your question along with the code you've tried, even if not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to `ROW_NUMBER` each the the "statuses" and then use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to get the 2 datasets into the appropriate columns. I use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` as I *assume* you could have a different amount of employees who were present/absent.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (Name varchar(10), --Using a name that doesn't require delimit identification
                            Status varchar(7), --Using a name that doesn't require delimit identification
                            Days int);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Name, Status, Days)
VALUES('Mal','Present',30),
      ('Jess','Present',20),
      ('Rick','Absent',30),
      ('Jerry','Absent',10);
GO

WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT Name,
           Status,
           Days,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Status ORDER BY Days DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT P.Name AS PresentName,
       P.Days AS PresentDays,
       A.Name AS AbsentName,
       A.Days AS AbsentDays
FROM (SELECT R.Name,
             R.Days,
             R.Status,
             R.RN
      FROM RNs R
      WHERE R.Status = 'Present') P
    FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT R.Name,
                            R.Days,
                            R.Status,
                            R.RN
                     FROM RNs R
                     WHERE R.Status = 'Absent') A ON P.RN = A.RN;    


GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6cf4e52bc7af93f388f8c5520fd0b0f6)

*2 CTE's is actually far neater:*

```sql
WITH Absents AS(
    SELECT Name,
           Status,
           Days,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Days DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE Status = 'Absent'),
Presents AS(
    SELECT Name,
           Status,
           Days,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Days DESC) AS RN
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE Status = 'Present')
SELECT P.Name AS PresentName,
       P.Days AS PresentDays,
       A.Name AS AbsentName,
       A.Days AS AbsentDays
FROM Absents A
     FULL OUTER JOIN Presents P ON A.RN = P.RN;
```